# Can any one tell me the difference between soap and rest?and where we use the soap and rest?

Tags: webservices, integration

Difference between Callout and Web services

Comment: Muneerdar, REST and SOAP are well established internet technologies and there are 100's of resources about these online. If you're question is about salesforce specific aspects please be so kind to update your question to be more specific. The current question(s) is/are immensly broad.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two schools of thought in developing Web Services – one being the standards-based traditional approach [ SOAP ] and the other, simpler school of thought [ REST ].
This article quickly compares one with the other –

**REST**

Assumes a point-to-point communication model–not usable for distributed computing environment where message may go through one or more intermediaries.
Minimal tooling/middleware is necessary. Only HTTP support is required.
URL typically references the resource being accessed/deleted/updated
Not reliable – HTTP DELETE can return OK status even if a resource is not deleted
Formal description standards not in widespread use. WSDL 1.2, WADL are candidates.
Better suited for point-to-point or where the intermediary does not play a significant role
No constraints on the payload
Only the most well established standards apply e.g. HTTP, SSL. No established standards for other aspects.  DELETE and PUT methods often disabled by firewalls, leads to security complexity.
Built-in error handling (faults)
Tied to the HTTP transport model
Less verbose

**SOAP**

Designed to handle distributed computing environments
Requires significant tooling/middleware support
The content of the message typically decides the operation e.g. doc-literal services
Reliable .Well defined mechanism for describing the interface e.g. WSDL+XSD, WS-Policy
Payload must comply with the SOAP schema.
A large number of supporting standards for security, reliability, transactions
No error handling
Both SMTP and HTTP are valid application layer protocols used asTransport for SOAP
More verbose